# Is there a way to limit the number of command line arguments?

Tags: c, bash, echo, argv, argc

I am trying to do an implementation of the command 'echo' in C.

I would like to have the entire sentence after the command 'echo' read into argv[1] in the command line instead of having each word passed as a separate argument.

Is that possible in C?

Comment: This is unrelated to the C language. The shell creates the argument list. In other word, not it's not possible.

Comment: you can use a loop and collect them into just one string using strncat syscall.

Comment: Or you can invoke your program like this `myecho "hello world"`, then `"hello world"` will be consideres as one argument by the shell and in your C  program `argv[1]` will point to `"hello world"`. But again this is a shell thing.

Comment: so if the argument is between "..." it is considered a single argument?

Comment: @ShiviBarlev yes, but this is unrelated to C, the shell is doing this.

Comment: In Windows, you can use the `GetCommandLineA` or `GetCommandLineW` functions to get the unsplit command line, because unlike Unix processes, it is actually the responsibility of the Windows process to split the command line into arguments. (For hosted C programs, this is done by the C start-up code before `main` is called.) You would still need to split off the initial argv[0] component.

Comment: Note that the real implementation of Unix echo is unlikely to join the arguments into a single string. Rather, it will output each argument individually with a space between each one and a newline at the end (although command line arguments may modify this behaviour to allow the trailing newline to be omitted, and to interpret various escape sequences in the argument strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because the shell is splitting the arguments even before your program starts.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char sentence[500] = { 0 };

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    strcat(sentence, argv[i]);
    if (i < argc - 1)
      strcat(sentence, " ");
  }

  printf("sentence = \"%s\"", sentence);
}
```

Disclaimer: no bounds checking is done for brevity.

Example of invoking:

```
> myecho Hello World 1 2 3
sentence = "Hello World 1 2 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather loop over every element of `argv` by using `argc` to ensure you you won't read too deep. 
You can also you require the launch of your programm to be : `./myProgram "Here is my nice sentence"`

Comment: thanks! i will probably do the second thing you said.